# What dependencies are there to run pandas pd.test()?

Tags: python, pandas, pip

After installing pandas via pip I tried running `pd.test()` per [these instructions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#running-the-test-suite) I'm getting errors that seem to indicate missing modules. Installed pytest and moto to resolve the first two and looks like google-compute-engine would be the next module it's looking for. Is there a list of the necessary modules somewhere to run `pd.test()`?

Maybe there's a better way to go about this. Normally I'd just install an anaconda environment but this is an existing python environment on a server.

Thanks.

Edit: Add errors

```
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan 16 2018, 13:13:52)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.test()
running: pytest --skip-slow --skip-network /opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas
============================================================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.4.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /opt/bitnami, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors

================================================================================================================== ERRORS ===================================================================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting  _____________________________________________________________________________________________________________
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py:329: in _getconftestmodules
    return self._path2confmods[path]
E   KeyError: local('/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tests/io')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py:360: in _importconftest
    return self._conftestpath2mod[conftestpath]
E   KeyError: local('/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tests/io/conftest.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py:366: in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:668: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:213: in load_module
    py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tests/io/conftest.py:3: in <module>
    import moto
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moto/__init__.py:8: in <module>
    from .acm import mock_acm  # flake8: noqa
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moto/acm/__init__.py:2: in <module>
    from .models import acm_backends
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moto/acm/models.py:7: in <module>
    from moto.ec2 import ec2_backends
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moto/ec2/__init__.py:2: in <module>
    from .models import ec2_backends
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moto/ec2/models.py:13: in <module>
    import boto.ec2
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/__init__.py:1216: in <module>
    boto.plugin.load_plugins(config)
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/plugin.py:93: in load_plugins
    _import_module(file)
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/plugin.py:75: in _import_module
    return imp.load_module(name, file, filename, data)
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/imp.py:235: in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/imp.py:172: in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/boto/compute_auth.py:19: in <module>
    from google_compute_engine import logger
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_compute_engine'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:377: in visit
    for x in Visitor(fil, rec, ignore, bf, sort).gen(self):
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:429: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:418: in gen
    dirs = self.optsort([p for p in entries
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:419: in <listcomp>
    if p.check(dir=1) and (rec is None or rec(p))])
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/main.py:411: in _recurse
    ihook = self.gethookproxy(path)
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/main.py:315: in gethookproxy
    my_conftestmodules = pm._getconftestmodules(fspath)
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py:343: in _getconftestmodules
    mod = self._importconftest(conftestpath)
../../../../python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py:368: in _importconftest
    raise ConftestImportFailure(conftestpath, sys.exc_info())
E   _pytest.config.ConftestImportFailure: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'google_compute_engine'",)
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 213, in load_module
E       py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tests/io/conftest.py", line 3, in <module>
E       import moto
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moto/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
E       from .acm import mock_acm  # flake8: noqa
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moto/acm/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
E       from .models import acm_backends
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moto/acm/models.py", line 7, in <module>
E       from moto.ec2 import ec2_backends
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moto/ec2/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
E       from .models import ec2_backends
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moto/ec2/models.py", line 13, in <module>
E       import boto.ec2
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/__init__.py", line 1216, in <module>
E       boto.plugin.load_plugins(config)
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/plugin.py", line 93, in load_plugins
E       _import_module(file)
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/plugin.py", line 75, in _import_module
E       return imp.load_module(name, file, filename, data)
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 235, in load_module
E       return load_source(name, filename, file)
E     File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
E       module = _load(spec)
E     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/boto/compute_auth.py", line 19, in <module>
E       from google_compute_engine import logger
============================================================================================================= warnings summary ==============================================================================================================
None
  could not create cache path /opt/bitnami/.pytest_cache/v/cache/lastfailed

-- Docs: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
==================================================================================================== 1 warnings, 1 error in 2.42 seconds ====================================================================================================
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

Currently installed packages:

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ ----------------------
asn1crypto               0.24.0
attrs                    17.4.0
aws-xray-sdk             0.96
boto                     2.48.0
boto3                    1.4.7
botocore                 1.7.43
Bottleneck               1.2.1
cachetools               2.0.1
certifi                  2018.1.18
cffi                     1.11.5
chardet                  3.0.4
cookies                  2.2.1
cryptography             2.1.4
decorator                4.2.1
Django                   2.0.2
djangorestframework      3.7.7
docker                   3.1.0
docker-pycreds           0.2.2
docutils                 0.12
elementtree              1.2.7-20070827-preview
firebase-admin           2.9.0
future                   0.16.0
gevent                   1.2.2
google-api-core          1.0.0
google-auth              1.4.1
google-cloud-core        0.28.1
google-cloud-firestore   0.29.0
google-cloud-storage     1.8.0
google-resumable-media   0.3.1
googleapis-common-protos 1.5.3
greenlet                 0.4.10
html5lib                 0.90
idna                     2.6
ipython                  6.2.1
ipython-genutils         0.2.0
jedi                     0.11.1
Jinja2                   2.10
jmespath                 0.9.3
jsondiff                 1.1.1
jsonpickle               0.9.6
lxml                     3.5.0
Markdown                 2.6.9
MarkupSafe               0.23
mock                     2.0.0
moto                     1.2.0
mysqlclient              1.3.12
numexpr                  2.6.4
numpy                    1.14.1
pandas                   0.22.0
parso                    0.1.1
pbr                      1.9.1
pexpect                  4.4.0
pickleshare              0.7.4
Pillow                   3.4.1
pip                      9.0.1
pluggy                   0.6.0
prompt-toolkit           1.0.15
protobuf                 3.5.1
psutil                   4.3.1
psycopg2                 2.7.1
ptyprocess               0.5.2
py                       1.5.2
pyaml                    17.12.1
pyasn1                   0.4.2
pyasn1-modules           0.2.1
pycairo                  1.15.3
pycparser                2.18
pycrypto                 2.6.1
pydot                    1.2.3
Pygments                 2.2.0
pyldap                   2.4.37
pyparsing                2.1.10
pytest                   3.4.1
python-dateutil          2.6.1
python-http-client       3.0.0
python-Levenshtein       0.12.0
python-openid            2.2.5
pytz                     2016.7
PyYAML                   3.12
reportlab                3.3.0
requests                 2.18.4
rsa                      3.4.2
s3transfer               0.1.11
scandir                  1.5
sendgrid                 5.3.0
setuptools               38.5.1
simplegeneric            0.8.1
simplejson               3.11.1
six                      1.10.0
stevedore                1.1.0
traitlets                4.3.2
urllib3                  1.22
virtualenv               15.1.0
virtualenv-clone         0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper        4.8.2
wcwidth                  0.1.7
websocket-client         0.47.0
Werkzeug                 0.14.1
wrapt                    1.10.11
XlsxWriter               1.0.2
xmltodict                0.11.0
```

Comment: You should, please, show us the errors that you are getting.

Comment: yeh i'm getting this too on Ubuntu 17.10 FWIW it works fine even tho the tests aren't running

Comment: Updated with errors and currently installed packages. @maxymoo pandas also works for me, at least for what I'm using it for right now. Would like the tests to run if possible though.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) the following are the dependencies of this module.

```
setuptools, NumPy, python-dateutil, pytz
```

I have had the same problem and I simply fixed it by installing pandas through the `PyCharm IDE`. I am not sure what difference if any, it makes; however, it worked.

Comment: These packages are already installed, but are apparently not sufficient to run `pd.test()`

Comment: @DanHampton What version of python are using? If you are using python3, make sure that pandas is installed for python3 as well using: `sudo -H pip3 install pandas` or on windows: `py -3   -m pip install pandas`